# I am not able to open my installed applications like vscode, rocketchat in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt

Some of my installed software is not opening, I reinstalled the software but still not opening. I can only run the chrome browser. It happened when I was trying to fix the docker.

I used these commands to fix but it did not work

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt update
```

Comment: "t happened when I was trying to fix the docker" needs further explanation to make any sense. [edit] your question accordingly with what you actually did to "fix it".

Comment: actually I am new to ubuntu and to fix docker I used many commands, and I forgot, maybe I need to reinstall ubuntu to fix it,

Comment: If you open terminal you can scroll through your history using the ⬆️ key then copy and paste the commands to your question. Hope that helps. If you do consider re-installing, backup important data first.